# bzip2 compression gives empty output when used from a generated shared library

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am trying to compress the incoming stream of data into a file using bzlib library.

When I run an individual program `g++ -lbz2 compress.cpp; ./a.out` to compress/decompress, it works seamlessly.

But when I create a compress.so file of the same code and call it in another run.so file, the compressed file (file.bz2) gets generated but it doesn't has any data in it.

I am linking the libbzip2 by adding

`-Wl,-R,/home/utils/bzip2-1.0.6/lib -Wl,--whole-archive -lbz2 -Wl,--no-whole-archive -shared` to Makefile which generate the compress.so file

I am not getting any error anywhere while running. 
Is there something wrong the way libbzip2 is getting linked?

Comment: Got it fixed.
There were two problems- One in the library I was using. My program flow works on a 32 bit system for some reason and the library I was using was 64 bit library. After changing the path to 32 bit lib, the compressed file getting generated was empty. Problem was in the way I was closing the handlers in my code. BZ2_bzCloseWrite() should be called before Close(<FILE>).